# How can an 8-bit computer have a 20-bit address bus?

Tags: memory-hardware, cpu

I'm in the middle of building a homemade processor from logic chips, and I've been trying to figure out how I can have RAM (for main memory) and ROM (for small booting stuff) on the bus at the same time. I came up with memory mapped I/O, but how do i make my 8-bit processor have a 20-bit address bus? (enough lines for 64 kiB of memory and 4 extra for decoding)

Or should i maybe have dedicated enable lines for RAM and ROM coming out of my instruction decoder?

Thanks.

Comment: This hardware question seems off-topic here.

Comment: You can look at examples : banked memory with memory mapped switches (Apple2 ram cards, many others), MMUs (MC6829 for the MC6809), segment registers with offset (8086), extensions to address registers (WDC65816), etc...